# OpenCL- waste of host computing power

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I am new to OpenCL, please tell me that the host cpu can be used only for allocating memory to the device, or we can use it can as an openCL device. (Because after the allocation is done, the host cpu will be idle).

Comment: Simply googling 'OpenCL CPU' gives you your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cpu as a compute device. Opencl even allows multicore/processor systems to segment cores into separate compute units. I like to use this feature to divide the cpus on my system into groups based on NUMA nodes. It is possible to divide a cpu into compute devices which all share the same level of cache memory (L1, L2, L3 or L4).

You need a platform that supports it, such as AMD's SDK. I know there are ways to have Nvidia and AMD platforms on the same machine, but I have never had to do so myself.

Also, the opencl event/callback system allows you to use your cpu as you normally would while the gpu kernels are executing. In this way, you can use openmp or any other code on the host while you wait for the gpu kernel to finish.

Comment: I've initialized and played with CPU and GPU compute contexts running simultaneously, but never in a production scenario. I expect that the VERY differents needs and speeds of both those compute devices would make it hard to juggle complex computations across both.

Comment: It will always be problem dependent. I read about a BLAS implementation where the cpu crunched the oddly-shaped edges of the matrix while the gpu handled the nice NxM inner matrices. This book* has an entire chapter about how to use cpu and gpu to compute non-uniform sized particle collisions.  *http://developer.amd.com/zones/OpenCLZone/universities/OpenCLTextBook/Pages/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason the CPU has to be idle, but it needs a separate job to do. Once you've submitted work to OpenCL you can:

1. Get on with something else, like preparing the next set of work, or performing calculation on something completely different.
2. Have the CPU set up as another compute device, and so submit a piece of work to it.

Personally I tend to find myself needing the first case more often as it's rare I find myself with two tasks that are independent and lend themselves to OpenCL style. The trick is keeping things balanced so you're not waiting a long time for the GPU task to finish, or having the GPU idle while the CPU is getting on with other work.

It's the same problem OpenGL coders had to conquer. Avoiding being CPU or GPU bound, and balancing between the two for best performance.